# How can we protect the excel sheet, but works expands of row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

How can i protect the excel sheet, to non-editing sheet but , the sheet having the expanding the row (+) ,that button should work while protect,

PIC 1:

[image]

PIC 2:

[image]

" i tried with protect , but the + sign will not work it showing a message it is a protected sheet.
i need to click + sign to expand that row details data." any one please suggest to solve this problem 
 am using office 2016 and office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following article...This is an old article and I'm not sure if it will work in 2016/365, but it's worth a quick look.

[Expand Groups is protected worksheets](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/expand-groups-protected-worksheet-excel-2007-61513.html)